# Marie has been taking note of the time she leaves for work and the length of her morning commute. She decided to model the number of hours $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

> Marie has been taking note of the time she leaves for work and the length of her morning commute. She decided to model the number of hours $X$ after **6:30** **a.m** that she leaves for work with a $uniform(2)$ distribution, ie $X$ has pdf:
>
> $\begin{equation*}
> f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
>             c & \quad 0<x<2  \\
>             0 & \quad\text{otherwise}
>         \end{cases}
> \end{equation*}$
>
> She notices that, when $0<x<2$ the length of the commute (in hours), $Y$, seems to depend upon the time she leaves for work and decides to model $Y|X$ with a distribution, with pdf:
>
> $\begin{equation*}
> f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = \begin{cases}
>             6+8(x-y) & \quad \frac{1}{4}+x<y<\frac{3}{4}+x  \\
>             0 & \quad\text{otherwise}
>         \end{cases}
> \end{equation*}$
>
> Note that $f_{Y\mid X}(x,y)$ is defined only for $0<x<2$
>
> $a.$ Determine the value of $c$
>
> $b.$ Find the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$, $f_X,_Y(x,y).$ Remember to include the range of the values of $x$ and $y$ for which the result holds.
>
> $c.$ Find that probability that Marie left home before **7:00** **am** and her commute is less than $45$ minutes.
>
> $d.$ Copy and complete following to rewrite $f_X,_Y(x,y).$ with $y$ as leading variable.
>
> $\begin{equation*}
> f_{Y,X}(y,x) = \begin{cases}
>             3+4(x-y) & \quad ...<y<...\max(...,0)<x<\min(2,...)  \\
>             0 & \quad\text{otherwise}
>         \end{cases}
> \end{equation*}$

**MY WORKING**

$a.$ By integrating the given pdf $f_X(x)$ over its domain I find that $c=\frac{1}{2}$

$b.$ Since $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{Y\mid X}(x\mid y)\cdot f_X(x)$. Since we know values of $f_{Y\mid X}(x\mid y)$ & $f_X(x)$ already. By putting them in the formulae I get:

$\begin{equation*}
f_{Y,X}(y, x) = \begin{cases}
            \frac{1}{2}\cdot [6+8(x-y)] & \quad 0<x<2, 0.25<y<2.75\\
            0 & \quad\text{ otherwise}
        \end{cases}
\end{equation*} $

I am having issue in the other two parts.

In part $c$; I am unable to write mathematically what the question asks. As a result I can't proceed further.

As for part $d$ I don't understand what does the phrase "rewrite $f_{X,Y}(x,y).$ with $y$ as leading variable. " even mean.

Any help and guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, $c=1/2$.

> $\qquad\begin{align}
> f_{X}(x)&=\begin{cases} 1/2 &:& 0<x<2\\0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
> \\[1ex]
> f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) &= \begin{cases}
>             6+8(x-y) &:& \frac{1}{4}+x<y<\frac{3}{4}+x  \\
>             0 &:&\text{otherwise}
>         \end{cases}
> \end{align}$

You are correct that the joint probability mass function is the product of these two functions.  However, the support of the joint pmf is the *intersection* of their supports. This can be presented in various ways, for example:

$\hspace{10ex}\begin{align}f_{X,Y}(x,y) &=\begin{cases}
            3+4(x-y) &:& 0<x<2~,~ x+1/4<y<x+3/4  \\
            0 &:&\text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}\\[2ex]&=\begin{cases}
            3+4(x-y) &:& 1/4<x+1/4<y<x+3/4<2+3/4  \\
            0 &:&\text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
\end{align}$

Part (d) just requests you to rewrite that support in the given format.